# Opencv Image Stitching or Panorama

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching

I am doing image stitching in OpenCV (A panorama) but I have one problem.

I can't use the class Stitching from OpenCV so I must create it with only feature points and homographies.

```
OrbFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );

std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints_1, keypoints_2;

Mat descriptors_1a, descriptors_2a;
detector.detect( img_1, keypoints_1 , descriptors_1a);
detector.detect( img_2, keypoints_2 , descriptors_2a);

//-- Step 2: Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
OrbDescriptorExtractor extractor;

Mat descriptors_1, descriptors_2;
cout<<"La distancia es " <<endl;
extractor.compute( img_1, keypoints_1, descriptors_1 );
extractor.compute( img_2, keypoints_2, descriptors_2 );

//-- Step 3: Matching descriptor vectors with a brute force matcher
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_HAMMING, true);
std::vector< DMatch > matches;
matcher.match( descriptors_1, descriptors_2, matches );
```

Here I obtain the feature points in matches, but I need to filter it:

```
 double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

  //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
  for( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
  {
      double dist = matches[i].distance;

  //cout<<"La distancia es " << i<<endl;
    if( dist < min_dist && dist >3)
        {

            min_dist = dist;
        }
    if( dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
  }

  //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
  std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;

  for( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ )
  {
      //cout<<matches[i].distance<<endl;
      if( matches[i].distance < 3*min_dist && matches[i].distance > 3)
     {
          good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); }
  }
```

Now, I calculate the Homography

```
vector<Point2f> p1, p2;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
        p1.push_back(keypoints_1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
        p2.push_back(keypoints_2[matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }

    // Homografía
    vector<unsigned char> match_mask;
    Mat h = findHomography(Mat(p1),Mat(p2), match_mask,CV_RANSAC);
```

ANd finally, obtain the transform matrix and apply `warpPerspective` to obtain the join of the two images,  but my problem is that in the final image, appears black areas around the photo, and when I loop again, the final image will be ilegible.

```
// Transformar perspectiva para imagen 2
    vector<Point2f> cuatroPuntos;
    cuatroPuntos.push_back(Point2f (0,0));
    cuatroPuntos.push_back(Point2f (img_1.size().width,0));
    cuatroPuntos.push_back(Point2f (0, img_1.size().height));
    cuatroPuntos.push_back(Point2f (img_1.size().width, img_1.size().height));
    Mat MDestino;
    perspectiveTransform(Mat(cuatroPuntos), MDestino, h);

    // Calcular esquinas de imagen 2
    double min_x, min_y, tam_x, tam_y;
    float min_x1, min_x2, min_y1, min_y2, max_x1, max_x2, max_y1, max_y2;
    min_x1 = min(MDestino.at<Point2f>(0).x, MDestino.at<Point2f>(1).x);
    min_x2 = min(MDestino.at<Point2f>(2).x, MDestino.at<Point2f>(3).x);
    min_y1 = min(MDestino.at<Point2f>(0).y, MDestino.at<Point2f>(1).y);
    min_y2 = min(MDestino.at<Point2f>(2).y, MDestino.at<Point2f>(3).y);
    max_x1 = max(MDestino.at<Point2f>(0).x, MDestino.at<Point2f>(1).x);
    max_x2 = max(MDestino.at<Point2f>(2).x, MDestino.at<Point2f>(3).x);
    max_y1 = max(MDestino.at<Point2f>(0).y, MDestino.at<Point2f>(1).y);
    max_y2 = max(MDestino.at<Point2f>(2).y, MDestino.at<Point2f>(3).y);
    min_x = min(min_x1, min_x2);
    min_y = min(min_y1, min_y2);
    tam_x = max(max_x1, max_x2);
    tam_y = max(max_y1, max_y2);

    // Matriz de transformación
    Mat Htr = Mat::eye(3,3,CV_64F);
    if (min_x < 0){
        tam_x = img_2.size().width - min_x;
        Htr.at<double>(0,2)= -min_x;
    }
    if (min_y < 0){
        tam_y = img_2.size().height - min_y;
        Htr.at<double>(1,2)= -min_y;
    }

    // Construir panorama
    Mat Panorama;
    Panorama = Mat(Size(tam_x,tam_y), CV_32F);
    warpPerspective(img_2, Panorama,     Htr, Panorama.size(), INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_CONSTANT,   0);
    warpPerspective(img_1, Panorama, (Htr*h), Panorama.size(), INTER_LINEAR, BORDER_TRANSPARENT,0);
```

Anyone knows how can I eliminate this black areas? Is something that I do bad? Anyone knows a functional code that I can see to compare it?

Thanks for your time

EDIT:

That is my image:

[image]

And I want to eliminate the black part.

Comment: when you stitch 2 images it's very unlikely that the panorama will end up in a real rectangle. So you can do two things to avoid black areas: 1. you find the inner rectangle of the panorama and crop away all the black areas together with some good panorama image parts. 2. you "stretch" the panorama image at the borders to fit any rectangle, afaik you should have to a look at "spline interpolation" for that. Tell me whatever method you want to achieve and I will try to help you further. Maybe post sample images and mark the areas you want to hold/crop ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Micka suggested, when you do stitching, the panorama is usually wavy, because homography or other projection methods do not map a rectangle to another rectangle. You can compensate this effect by using some "straightening", referring to this article:

M. Brown and D. G. Lowe. Automatic panoramic image stitching using invariant features. IJCV, 74(1):59–73, 2007

As to cropping the black part, I wrote this class that you can use. This class assumes the image is BGR and the black pixels have value Vec3b(0,0,0). The source code can be accessed here:

https://github.com/chmos/crop-images.git

Best,

Comment: Im making a stitcher myself but not just a pano. It can stitch in both x and y axis if that makes sense. I was wondering if you could explain your code especially the section with the Mat HTR::eye. I had figured out I needed to perspective transform both images onto a blank canvas/image but that section you have is the missing piece of the puzzle for me. Thanks for your help in advance.